# Real Time Firebase Query

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Firebase DB with the below structure:

[image]

and the rules are:

[image]

I'm using a python script to save and read DB data.  I would like to find the "d1" value. 
For example, when using the below code it returns null:

```
ref = db.reference('Test')
query = ref.order_by_child('f1').equal_to('alal-55')
snapshot = query.get()
for key,val in snapshot.items():
    print(val)
```

Any solution?
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query `ref.order_by_child('f1').equal_to('alal-55')` will not work, because the structure of your database is very deep. You need to change the structure to be able to perform the queries for example:

```
Test
  random_id
      f1 : value
```

Using the above, you can use `order_by_child`